# Is there a elegant way to convert a positive number to a +1 and a negative number to a -1?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a high-performance component that needs to convert a values to -1, +1 or 0.

```
    static int ToOne(double value) {
        return (int)(value == 0D ? value : value / Math.Abs(value));
    }
```

The above methods are not elegant, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by that Title and what is your code doing? If value is not 0 you are diving the value by its absolute value. How is this +1 or -1. You can simply say: if(value > 0) return 1 else if (value < 0) return -1 else return 0;  --- what doesnt work there?

Comment: If you divide a number by -itself then -1 it gives 1 or -1 then you just need a 0 check. `x==0?0:x/-x/-1`. Not sure if that meets the description of "elegant" though

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava because `2/abs(2)=1` and `-2/abs(-2)=-1` so math.abs is a valid way of turning any number into +-1. Maybe he is playing code golf

Answer (score 4):

You have basically recreated [`Math.Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign?view=netframework-4.8):

> Returns an integer that indicates the sign of a number.

```
Return value    Meaning
-1              value is less than zero.
0               value is equal to zero.
1               value is greater than zero.
```

Test code:

```
Console.WriteLine(ToOne(-5));
Console.WriteLine(ToOne(-0.1));
Console.WriteLine(ToOne(0));
Console.WriteLine(ToOne(0.1));
Console.WriteLine(ToOne(5));
```

Outputs:

```
-1
-1
0
1
1
```

And with `Math.Sign`:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(-5));
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(-0.1));
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(0));
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(0.1));
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(5));
```

Outputs:

```
-1
-1
0
1
1
```

Comment: The Java version of `Math.Sign`, (known as `Math.signum`) is literally `return (a < 0.0) ? -1.0 : ((a > 0.0) ? 1.0 : a)`. There's no need to try and be smart, as you'll end up being more complex. John is right, just use `Math.Sign`.

Comment: @JMadelaine why does the java version return the negative number itself instead of -1?

Comment: It returns `a` when `a == 0`, which is the same as returning `0`.